# how to do async test(pytest) in fastapi with error `There is 1 other session using the database`

Tags: asynchronous, pytest, fastapi

While I was writing the Async test code for FASTAPI there is a problem that cannot be solved. this code is for test db. I'm using postgres and in order to user db as a test, I created is_testing function. It drop and create test db.

```py
        if is_testing: 
            db_url = self._engine.url
            if db_url.host != "localhost":
                raise Exception("db host must be 'localhost' in test environment")
            except_schema_db_url = f"{db_url.drivername}://{db_url.username}@{db_url.host}"   
            schema_name = db_url.database         # test                                                    
            temp_engine = create_engine(except_schema_db_url, echo=echo, pool_recycle=pool_recycle, pool_pre_ping=True)
            conn = temp_engine.connect()
            try:
                conn = conn.execution_options(autocommit=False)
                conn.execute("ROLLBACK")
                conn.execute(f"DROP DATABASE {schema_name}")
            except ProgrammingError:
                print(f"could not drop the database, probably does not exist.")
                conn.execute("ROLLBACK")
            except OperationalError:
                print("could not drop database because it's being accessed by other users(psql prompt open?)")
                conn.execute("ROLLBACK")
            print(f"test db dropped! about to create {schema_name}")
            conn.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {schema_name}")
            try:
                conn.execute(f"create user test with encrypted password test")
            except:
                print("User already exist")
            temp_engine.dispose()
```

this is conftest.py

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app():
    os.environ["API_ENV"] = "test"
    return create_app()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def client(app):
    Base.metadata.create_all(db.engine)
    # Create tables
    client = AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test")
    return client

@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def session():
    sess = next(db.session())
    yield sess
    clear_all_table_data(
        session=sess,
        metadata=Base.metadata,
        except_tables=[]
    )
    sess.rollback()

def clear_all_table_data(session: Session, metadata, except_tables: List[str] = None):
    session.execute("SET session_replication_role = 'replica';")          
    for table in metadata.sorted_tables:
        if table.name not in except_tables:
            session.execute(table.delete())
    session.execute("SET session_replication_role = 'origin';")         
    session.commit()
```

I got error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.errors.ObjectInUse) database "test" is being accessed by other users DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.` in elb check test.

and I got error  `TypeError: 'AsyncClient' object is not callable` in another api test.

I modified client function in conftest.py

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def client(app):
    Base.metadata.create_all(db.engine)
    return AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test")
```

I passed one test, but I received the following error from the second test.

```py
ClientState.OPENED: "Cannot open a client instance more than once.",
ClientState.CLOSED: "Cannot reopen a client instance, once it has been closed.",
```

how can I fix it?
thank you for reading long question!